# Why Bulma CSS Frameworks uses <p> instead of <div>

Tags: bulma

Form example

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Name</label>
  <p class="control">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
  </p>
</div>
```

Why it uses `<p class="control">` instead of `<div class="control">`?

Answer (score 2):

p and div act pretty much the same in this instance. You can use either one. Both are block level elements. For this example snippet, the person decided to use p instead of div. There's nothing more to it.